# Placeholder mixin Less

Tags: css, less, placeholder

At the moment I try to create a small less mixin to add styles to placeholders.
The values are passed through an object. My solution now looks like this:

```
.placeholder(@rules){
   &::-webkit-input-placeholder, &:-moz-placeholder, 
   &::-moz-placeholder,&:-ms-input-placeholder{
      @rules();
   }
}
```

I try to use this mixin like this:

```
input{
   .placeholder({color:green})
}
```

So less generates:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder, input:-moz-placeholder, 
input::-moz-placeholder, input:-ms-input-placeholder{
    color: green;
}
```

The code evens has been generated like I want it, but the wished effect not entered. But when I cut the code and fill it in devtools it works.
Does anybody find a mistake. I don't get it

Comment: You should not put different vendor prefixes to the same selector list (since a browser can understand only its own prefixes and treats foreign elements as invalid CSS, the whole list is not accepted as invalid).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/#comment-96772):

> That would be nice, but the problem is that when a browser doesn’t understand a selector, it invalidates the entire line of selectors (except IE 7).

So you'll have to seperate the placeholder selectors:

```
.placeholder(@rules){
   &::-webkit-input-placeholder{
      @rules();
   }

   &:-moz-placeholder{
      @rules();
   }

   &::-moz-placeholder{
      @rules();
   }

   &:-ms-input-placeholder{
      @rules();
   }
}
```